# Метод Ньютона для комплексных чисел

Tags: c++

Здраствуйте, должен решить уравнение z^3 - 1 = 0, z - комплексное число.

1. Код работает, только вывод один корень из трех, но верный. Что нудно сделать, чтобы выводило три корня? Как мне кажется, проблема в том, что нигде не задается (не передается) стартовая точка и по этому один корень, а так бы для разных точек были бы разные корни, но я в этом не уверен.
2. На основе результатов нужно будет сделать график бассейнов решений, т.е от это будет комплексная плоскость, на которой каждый пиксель будет приводить одному из решений. Как это сделать, может кто-то знает? Как мне кажется, это должно быть два цикла с очень маленьким шагом, но что дальше?

Код :

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CComplex
{
public :
    double _re;
    double _im;
    CComplex();
    CComplex(double re, double im);
    CComplex(const CComplex &pCopy);

    CComplex conjugate();
    double complexfabs();

    CComplex operator + (CComplex pAdd);
    CComplex operator - (CComplex pAdd);
    CComplex operator * (CComplex pMul);
    CComplex operator / (CComplex pDiv);

    CComplex uintpower(unsigned int n);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const CComplex pVal)
    {
        out<<pVal._re<<(pVal._im < 0 ? " - " : " + ")<<fabs(pVal._im)<<"i";
        return out;
    }
};

CComplex::CComplex()
{
    _re = _im = 0;
}

CComplex::CComplex(double re, double im)
{
    _re = re;
    _im = im;
}

CComplex::CComplex(const CComplex &pCopy)
{
    _re = pCopy._re;
    _im = pCopy._im;
}

CComplex
CComplex::conjugate()
{
    CComplex pThis = (*this);
    pThis._im *= -1;
    return pThis;
}

double CComplex::complexfabs()
{
    return _re*_re + _im*_im;
}

CComplex
CComplex::operator +(CComplex pAdd)
{
    CComplex pThis = (*this);
    pThis._re += pAdd._re;
    pThis._im += pAdd._im;
    return pThis;
}

CComplex
CComplex::operator - (CComplex pAdd)
{
    CComplex pThis = (*this);
    pThis._re -= pAdd._re;
    pThis._im -= pAdd._im;
    return pThis;
}

CComplex
CComplex::operator *(CComplex pMul)
{
    CComplex pThis = (*this);
    pThis._re = _re*pMul._re - _im*pMul._im;
    pThis._im = _re*pMul._im + _im*pMul._re;
    return pThis;
}

CComplex
CComplex::operator / (CComplex pDiv)
{
    CComplex pThis = (*this);
    double divider = pDiv.complexfabs();
    pThis = pThis*pDiv.conjugate();
    pThis._re /= divider;
    pThis._im /= divider;
    return pThis;
}

CComplex
CComplex::uintpower(unsigned int n)
{
    CComplex pThis = CComplex(1, 0);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        pThis = pThis*(*this);
    return pThis;
}

CComplex f(CComplex z, unsigned int n)
{
    return z.uintpower(n) - CComplex(1, 0);
}

CComplex df(CComplex z, unsigned int n)
{
    return CComplex(n, 0)*z.uintpower(n - 1);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int n = 3;
    unsigned int i;
    double err = 1e-12;
    CComplex z(1,1);



    std::cout << "First root" <<std::endl;
    for(i = 0; f(z, n).complexfabs() > err; i++)
    {
        z = z - f(z, n) / df(z, n);
        cout<<"\riteration "<<i + 1<<" root : "<<z<<std::endl;    
    }
   system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он по математике, а не по программированию.

Comment: Нужно решить уравнение на бумаге, проследить алгоритм - а потом уже переносить алгоритм в компьютер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кубический корень имеет три ответа, между каждыми ответами разница `2π/3` в угловом смысле. Вам нужно перевести первый ответ в экспонентный формат `x+iy=r*exp(iw)`. Другие ответы будут  `r*exp(i(w-2π/3))` и `r*exp(i(w+2π/3))`. Дальше эти ответы перевести назад.

```
r:=sqrt(x*x+y*y)
w:=atan2(y,x)

w2:=w-2π/3 
w3:=w+2π/3 

x2:=r*cos(w2)
y2:=r*sin(w2)

x3:=r*cos(w3)
y3:=r*sin(w3)
```

Пример вывода трёх решений:

```
    for(i = 0; f(z, n).complexfabs() > err; i++)
    {
        z = z - f(z, n) / df(z, n);
        cout<<"\riteration "<<i + 1<<" root : "<<z<<std::endl;   
                double r = sqrt(z._re*z._re+z._im*z._im);
                double w = atan2(z._im,z._re);
                double const PI = 3.1416;
                CComplex z2(r*cos(w-2.0*PI/3.0),r*sin(w-2.0*PI/3.0));
                cout<<"\riteration "<<i + 1<<" root : "<<z2<<std::endl;
                CComplex z3(r*cos(w+2.0*PI/3.0),r*sin(w+2.0*PI/3.0));
                cout<<"\riteration "<<i + 1<<" root : "<<z3<<std::endl;        
} //for
```

Ответом может быть при начальной точке (-1,1) такой:

```
iteration 1 root : -0.666667 + 0.833333i
iteration 1 root : 1.05502 + 0.160678i
iteration 1 root : -0.38835 - 0.994019i
iteration 2 root : -0.508692 + 0.8411i
iteration 2 root : 0.98276 + 0.0199854i
iteration 2 root : -0.474064 - 0.861092i
iteration 3 root : -0.49933 + 0.866269i
iteration 3 root : 0.999876 - 0.000707022i
iteration 3 root : -0.500542 - 0.865569i
iteration 4 root : -0.5 + 0.866025i
iteration 4 root : 1 - 4.72405e-06i
iteration 4 root : -0.499995 - 0.866028i
iteration 5 root : -0.5 + 0.866025i
iteration 5 root : 1 - 4.89761e-06i
iteration 5 root : -0.499996 - 0.866028i
```

Главный ответ `-0.5 + 0.866025i` отличается от основного ответа, но ответ красивый можно получить из второго решения.

Comment: @AlexGlebeТуплю, что значит перенести эти корни назад?

Comment: Ответы r,w2 и r,w3 -> x2,y2 и x3,y3 .

Comment: есть ли возможность с Вами связаться?@AlexGlebe

Comment: Разница между тремя ответами - точная, а приближение в цикле если даёт точность `eps`, то все три ответа будут иметь ошибку `eps`.

Comment: Теория понятна, только я не до конца понимаю как это должно быть на коде и то, что Вы описали это получается как бы "трюк", но опять же в этом случае нет метода Ньютона, где я задаю отправную точку. Если не прав, поправте меня, пожалуйста.

Comment: Если бы вы сделали отправную точку другую (например `(-1,1)`) то результатом алгоритма был бы другой ответ `(-0.5 + 0.866025i)`. Ответ алгоритма Ньютона *единственный*, а два других ответа вы должны дописать сами.

Comment: Я не пишу вам этот метод,а отвечаю на просьбу найти другие решения.

Comment: Но мне на базе моих трех корней(речь идет об итерациях в которых вычисляются данные три корня) нужно построить график бассейнов акций и  я так понимаю, что это не получится сделать, если я решу данным способом?

Comment: Посмотрите ответ, я не виноват, что у кубического корня три ответа. Это всего-лишь математика.